# OnClick function using jquery tabs in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-tabs

I am using jquery tabs and trying to use the onclick function but it seems it is not firing.  When user clicks the tab and i want to change the detailview mode into readonly mode.  Here is my code in aspx:

```
<div id="tabs-2" class="column" onclick="ChangeMode">
```

and here code behind:

```
 protected void ChangeMode()
        {
             if (DV_Test.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
            {
                DV_Test.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
                LoadDet();
            }
        }
```

I am using this code that forces the pageto stay the selected tab when post pack occurs and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var selected_tab = 1;
        $(function () {
            var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
                select: function (e, i) {
                    selected_tab = i.index;

                }
            });
            selected_tab = $("[id$=selected_tab]").val() != "" ? parseInt($("[id$=selected_tab]").val()) : 0;
            tabs.tabs('select', selected_tab);
            $("form").submit(function () {
                $("[id$=selected_tab]").val(selected_tab);

            });

        });
```

Comment: Missing the onclick="ChangeMode();"  (??)  Is it firing the event at all?

Comment: Your `div` is a client-side element, but your function is server-side.  The client-side code has no notion of server-side code and can't directly access it.

Comment: Since you are mixing server-side and client-side code, this won't work. However, it's impossible to correct you without knowing what you are trying to achieve in this method. Whatever changes you make to `DV_Test` server-side are not going to affect what you see on the page (and likely not be persisted, either, unless `DV_Test.ChangeMode` performs database updates or similar. Please explain in more detail what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't using ajax solve the problem of sending requests to the server and updating the page (if you so choose)?

Comment: i am simply trying to change my DetailView mode into "ReadOnly" mode once the tab is clicked.  i am newbnie and that is why i am seeking your expertise as you can see i am mixing the clientside and the serverside.  thanks

Comment: pls tell me or show me a direction how to solve this issue as i am struggling to figure out... thanks

Comment: @Jose That is entirely dependent upon what `DV_Test` is and what is supposed to happen when that method is fired - simply calling it via Ajax is unlikely to solve the problem and - without knowing what it's supposed to do - it's impossible to expand upon that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using ASP.NET C# because of your tags and syntax.  I can suggest these options: use [Razor view](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views), or use the JavaScript/jQuery you're already using.

If you prefer to use the Razor View, take a look at the references in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129712/razor-views-in-asp-net-web-project) and use the `@` symbol to call server functions.  In this case, `@ChangeMode` is what you're looking for.

Since you're using jQuery already I suggest you write a JavaScript function using [jQuery `.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).  Since the JavaScript and jQuery are both able to call the server, you will be able to access your server-side function `ChangeMode`.

> ```
> $('#tabs-2').click(function(){
>     //Make call to server here.  You can use [Ajax][4], 
>     //or see the link below concerning ASP.NET C#
> });
> ```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function), see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoyalleBlue/2ku84/2/)

---

Ajax calls:

I've found the jQuery .ajax() call very useful, and this is what my .ajax() calls usually look like:

> ```
> //get information from server and inject in my div with id="mydiv"
> $.ajax({
>     url: '/ControllerName/MethodName',
>     type: 'POST',
>     data: ko.toJSON({myvariable}),
>     dataType: "json",
>     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>     success: function (data) {
>        $('#mydiv').html('visiblity', 'visible');
>     },
>     error: function (error) {
>        alert('Cannot retrieve data');
>     }
> });
> ```

---

Also, I'm not sure what you've decided on using, but I liked these suggestions for tabs: try the html found [here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2007/11/07/how-to-create-tabs-using-jquery), which uses `ul`/`li` and `a` to make the tabs themselves. The thing that triggers the action is typically the `a`.

Comment: thanks, i have tried but did not fire at all.  I simply tried to show this $("#target").click(function() {  alert("Handler for .click() called.");});   and it did not work

Comment: Do you have Razor View? Also, are you using ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC?  I can write you an answer using Razor View, but I'm unsure of which technology you're using.

Comment: You can isolate the problem by forking and trying out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoyalleBlue/2ku84/2/)

Comment: Also my second option doesn't work [when isolated](http://jsfiddle.net/RoyalleBlue/MsK2N/). I will delete it soon.

Comment: i am using asp.net web forms.  thanks for your help i really appreciate if you can help me out here

Comment: I checked to make sure that you can use Razor View in Web Forms.  You can use the link I provided in my answer to make a @server call.  Please try the suggestions I made and let me know what happened; letting me know what happened in each situation helps me help you.

Comment: i see the example that you shows in fiddle works fine but it does not work for me when i implement it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31694/discussion-between-royalleblue-and-moe)